# add extra arguments for search query wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my code:

```
global $query_string;
$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=-1&meta_key=post_views_count');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();    

endwhile;
```

this code works in taxonomy archive page but in search.php it isn't working no search result. What is wrong with my code ? I just want to add ordering for search results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
global $query_string;
query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=-1&meta_key=post_views_count');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();    

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```